# Ajax read large json file slowly

Tags: json, ajax, performance, autocomplete

I am using AJAX to read a large JSON file (about 15 MB minified), in order to display autocomplete suggestions on a text field.

The problem is that after user types 4 characters in order the suggestions to begin, i have to wait around 20 to 60 seconds which makes actually impossible to use it.

I don't know any techniques how i could make it read the JSON file faster.

I would like to read your suggestions...

My AJAX request is :

$(document).ready(function () {

```
$("#card").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                term: request.term,
            },
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            },
            cache: true,
            url: base_url+'/test123/wp-content/plugins/trading-collectible-cards/public/js/AllSets.json',
            success: function (data) {

var keys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames (data)
var outputArray;

    $.each(keys,function(ele, val){

var array = $.map(data[val].cards, function (set) {
                    return {
                        label: set.name + " (" +data[val].name + ")",
                        value: set.name,
                        text: set.text,
                        multi: set.multiverseid,
                        rarity: set.rarity,
                        setname:keys[ele],
                        setfull:data[val].name
                    }
                });     
  if (ele == 0)
       outputArray = $.merge([], array);
  else {
       outputArray = $.merge(outputArray, array);
   }  
});
    response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(outputArray, request.term));
},
    error: function (data) {
}
        });
    },
    minLength: 3,
    open: function () {

    },
    close: function () {

    },
    focus: function (event, ui) {

    },
    select: function (event, ui) {
        $( "#card" ).val( ui.item.label );
        $( "#description" ).html( ui.item.text );

    }
});
```

Comment: Only way to really make it faster is to break up the JSON file into smaller chunks.

Comment: What will be the difference, the ajax will have again to search all these smaller chunks (as the user types in text field)...

Comment: How static is the data in the JSON file? Could it make more sense to consume it periodically and store in a more practical data store e.g. a database.

Comment: It's static. It will be updated once per 3-4 months and only additions at the end of it.